# How can I avoid setTimeout and redundant getEntityRecord calls in a block editor sidebar?

Tags: block-editor

I've been struggling with getCurrentUser, getEntityRecord, and editEntityRecord and am wondering how I should be using them.

It's for a sidebar that submits a prompt to OpenAI and then returns it. It shows the result as well as the previous 10 prompts and results.

Here's the complete code, below. It's doing this in a PluginSidebar in the block editor/Gutenberg:

1. When page loads, load history (with useEffect)
2. When a new result is received, update history
3. When the panel is closed and re-opened, state is lost, so load history again

History in this case is stored in user meta; I wanted it to be unique to each user.

There are a number of odd things that it seems like may be because I'm doing something wrong:

- When useEffect() calls getHistory(), it has to run inside a setTimeout() or it'll fail on initial page load
- getCurrentUser() caches its results so I have to use getEntityRecord() instead to handle #2 and #3 above
- But getEntityRecord() results are undefined (even inside a subscribe() with isResolving()) on page load, so at that time I have to use getCurrentUser instead
- warmUpEntityRecord() has to run on initial page load, or subsequent calls will fail

This is probably confusing to read; I know it's confusing to me!

The code works, but it must be unnecessarily complex and hacky. Do you know the correct way of handling these issues? Any and all advice welcome.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useSelect, useDispatch, subscribe } from '@wordpress/data';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import Compose from './compose';
import History from './history';

export default function AiWriter() {
    const [historyItems, setHistoryItems] = useState([]);
    const [resultLoading, setResultLoading] = useState(false);
    const [historyLoading, setHistoryLoading] = useState(true);

    const apiKey = fjSidekick.openaiApiKey; // eslint-disable-line no-undef
    const apiURL = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions';
    const numberOfHistoryItems = 10;

    const isResolving = useSelect((select) => {
        return select('core/data').isResolving;
    }, []);

    const getCurrentUser = useSelect((select) => {
        return select('core').getCurrentUser;
    }, []);

    const getEntityRecord = useSelect((select) => {
        return select('core').getEntityRecord;
    }, []);

    const { editEntityRecord, saveEditedEntityRecord } = useDispatch('core');

    // This prevents editEntityRecord from failing with an "undefined" error on its first call
    const warmUpEditEntityRecord = async () => {
        await getEntityRecord('root', 'user', 1, {});
        await editEntityRecord('root', 'user', 1, {});
        await saveEditedEntityRecord('root', 'user', 1);
    };

    // Why do I have to use getCurrentUser() as a fallback on page load?
    const getHistory = async () => {
        setHistoryLoading(true);
        const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

        // Returns undefined on page load, even with isResolving()
        const updatedUserRecord = await getEntityRecord(
            'root',
            'user',
            currentUser.id
        );

        if (updatedUserRecord) {
            // On panel re-open and history refresh
            setHistoryItems(updatedUserRecord.meta?.fj_sidekick_history?.items);
            setHistoryLoading(false);
        } else {
            // On page load
            const unsubscribe = subscribe(() => {
                const isResolvingCurrentUser = isResolving(
                    'core',
                    'getCurrentUser'
                );
                if (!isResolvingCurrentUser) {
                    unsubscribe();

                    setHistoryItems(currentUser.meta.fj_sidekick_history.items);
                    setHistoryLoading(false);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // This works fine thanks to the warm-up function
    const addHistoryItem = async (prompt, newResult, length) => {
        const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
        const meta = (currentUser && currentUser.meta) || [];
        const history = (meta && meta.fj_sidekick_history) || null;
        const items = (history && history.items) || [];
        const newItems = [...items, { prompt, result: newResult, length }];

        while (numberOfHistoryItems < newItems.length) {
            newItems.shift();
        }

        const newMeta = {
            ...meta,
            fj_sidekick_history: {
                ...history,
                items: newItems,
            },
        };

        await editEntityRecord('root', 'user', currentUser.id, {
            meta: newMeta,
        });
        await saveEditedEntityRecord('root', 'user', currentUser.id);

        getHistory();
    };

    // No problems here
    const updateHistory = async (prompt, length) => {
        setResultLoading(true);

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + apiKey,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                model: 'text-davinci-002',
                prompt,
                temperature: 0,
                max_tokens: length,
            }),
        };

        const response = await fetch(apiURL, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
        const newResult =
            data && data.choices && data.choices[0]
                ? data.choices[0].text.trim()
                : __('No result', 'fj-sidekick');

        setResultLoading(false);

        addHistoryItem(prompt, newResult, length);
    };

    // Here lies weirdness
    useEffect(() => {
        warmUpEditEntityRecord();
        setTimeout(() => {
            getHistory();
        }, 0);
    }, []);

    // History items are shared between the two sections of the sidebar
    return (
        <>
            <Compose
                historyItems={historyItems}
                historyLoading={historyLoading}
                updateHistory={updateHistory}
                resultLoading={resultLoading}
            />
            <History
                historyItems={historyItems}
                historyLoading={historyLoading}
            />
        </>
    );
}
```